# orchestrator error UiPath.Core.SelectorNotFoundException: Could not find the UI element corresponding to this selector

Tags: uipath, uipath-orchestrator

Hi i have serius problem
I have done a job with uipath that works manuell execution on Test server and prod servern
But when i use the orchestrator it crashes anyone else have got this problem?
UiPath.Core.SelectorNotFoundException: Could not find the UI element corresponding to this selector
And how it get it fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the target was to static and id inserted a
tag=gen-57
to become
tag=gen-*

Answer (score 0):

It is a selector issue through the orchestrator it won't be possible to fix it permanently, you need to use the UiPath Studio to repair the selector. [selector screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeZpm.png)